# Deriving a differential equation form given another equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I'm trying to start from the LHS, **alpha** and am trying to get to the middle, the differential equation form, ignoring constants. I'm not familiar with differential equations so I decided to just "go for it".

Note: H is the heaviside, and this models the dynamics of a neuron. Since we're not interested in the evolution of a neuron in negative time, I'm just dropping it out.

$$
\begin{aligned}
  v &= H(t) e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}\frac{t}{\tau} & \text{H is heavidside}\\
  v' &= \frac{1}{\tau} e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}} - \frac{1}{\tau} e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}} \frac{t}{\tau}& \text{By the product rule} \\
  v' &= \frac{1}{\tau} e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}} (1 - \frac{t}{\tau}) & \\
  \tau v' &= e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}} (1 - \frac{t}{\tau}) & \\
\end{aligned}
$$

At this point, I'm stuck. I sort of get that I'm supposed to swap in x for $e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}$ and do some manipulation but:

1. I'm not sure what the exact steps are, and I can't justify them
2. if I weren't presented with the equations in the middle, I wouldn't know that I should move beyond what I've already derived. How do people know to keep simplifying and extracting variables? I'm assuming that it has something to do with the matrix form, in the far right(?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Heaviside is not differentiable in 0, you either need to consider distribution differentiation or define it for $t\neq 0$. This looks more like physics than mathematics

Comment: There is a typo in the equation $\tau x= -x$. It should be $\tau x'=-x$.

Comment: @Gonçalo Can you give me a hint into how to proceed? Was I right in my substituting x for the exponential?

Comment: You are on the right track. Just check whether $x=e^{-t/\tau}$ satisfies all three equations in the middle.